# Restricting the domain and codomain to make a bijective function

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to solve how you could restrict the domain and codomain — without changing the mapping rule — to make the below function both injective and surjective, while also keeping the domain and co-domain as large as possible

$h : 2^{[1..n]} → [0..2n]$ given by $h(S) = |S|$ where $n ≥ 2$

Where $2^{[1..n]}$ is the powerset of [1..n] and [1..n] is an integer interval. So if n=2, then $2^{[1..n]}$ = $[\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\}]$

The only solution I can think of is to define the function to $h : 2^{[n]} → [0..1]$

But this misses the mark of keeping the domain and co-domain large... What am I missing here, if anything?

Comment: Are you sure your function has codomain $[0,\dots,2n]$? Isn't it $[0,\dots,2^n]$?

Comment: Can you clarify notation $[1\cdots n]$?  Is it just the set of numbers from $1$ through $n$, or something else?

Comment: yes, codomain is definitely [1..2n]. [1..n] and [1..2n] are integer intervals. So yes, the numbers 1 through n.

Answer (score 1):

In general you may always restrict a function $f\colon X\to Y$ to a bijection $f|_A\colon A\to f(X)$ for some subset $A\subseteq X$, by simply picking out one element from the pre-image of each member of the range $f(X)$.  You can do this for finite sets even without the axiom of choice.  This is the largest you can manage, since you won't ever be able to get a bijection onto a set beyond the range of the original function without changing the values of that function.

In your case (if I am understanding your notation correctly), you can simply define $A=[\emptyset,[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],\dots, [1,2,3\dots n]]$, and restrict the codomain to $h(2^{[1,\dots,n]})=[0,1,\dots,n]$.

Comment: That's for the input. But wouldn't the powerset, A, include each separate elements as it's own set with one elements? e.g., $A = [/emptyset, [1], [2], [3], [1,3].... [1,2,3]]$. And then we'd see repeated cardinality for 1,2,3?

Comment: @cdub the set $A$ in this answer is not the power set. In your notation it contains only the sets $[1..k]$ for $k$ between $0$ and $n$.

Comment: @cdub as Mees de Vries said, $A$ Is not the power set, for each number $k$ between $0$ and $n$, it *by definition* includes exactly one set of cardinality $k$, namely $[1,2,\dots,k]$ (or $\emptyset$ in the case $k=0$).  So, for example, $A$ includes $[1]$ but does not include $[2]$, or any other singleton.

Comment: ah! I get it!! That makes sense. Not sure why I felt constrained to keeping the powerset notation for the domain. Thanks all